# show pertinent messages when validating input fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two input fields, username, and password. I perform a basic check for empty value for each, if either is empty the return is false and so the .$ajax request does not get executed. That works.

I would like to ask for help to enhance the check for empty value, and the return false.

If an email is entered, but no password, then I get password message error, and return false, but if then I enter password, no email, I then get the enter email error, but the password error stays on the page even if the previously entered value was not removed. this causes in the end to have both messages appear on the page, and that is misleading.

Same happens in the case of password, same steps.

It is important for my task to ensure the values are entered and the pertinent messages are displayed correctly, before the .$ajax request gets executed.

Below there is a copy of my script.

I hope someone has time to give me some help.

Thank you very much.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShoppingCartLogin() {

    var userid = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginEmail").val();
    var password = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginPassword").val();
    var url = "/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCartLogin";

    if (userid == "") {
        $('.YourOrder_loginError').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.YourOrder_loginError').text('Enter your e-mail address.');
        return false
    } 

    if (password == "") {
        $('.YourOrder_loginError_password').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.YourOrder_loginError_password').text('Enter your password.');
        return false
    } 

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { userId: userid, pass: password },//{ userId: userid, pass: password },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == "Valid") {
                // hide the login form and clear and hide error
                $('.YourOrder_loginError').text('');
                $('.YourOrder_loginError').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $('.YourOrder_loginForm').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                // show the shipping address section
                $('.YourOrder_ShipAddress').css('visibility', 'visible');
                location.reload();
            }
            if (result.error == "Invalid") {
                // hide shipping address section
                $('.YourOrder_ShipAddress').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $('.YourOrder_loginError').css('visibility', 'visible');
                $('.YourOrder_loginError').text('The user name or password provided is incorrect.');

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: The proper way to do it is `<input ... required />`. This lets the browser handle it natively, which is always good. You can customise the error text with `title="..."`

Comment: Add `else` clauses to both your `if` statements that hides the error message.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, thank you for the recommendation. I will read about it and try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the script and hide all messages before validation. For following HTML:

```
<form class="YourOrder_loginForm" method="post" action="https://">
    <p>
        <input class="YourOrder_MainLoginEmail" type="email" placeholder="email" />
        <span class="msg_error YourOrder_loginError">Please enter your email.</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="YourOrder_MainLoginPassword" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <span class="msg_error YourOrder_loginError_password">Please enter your password.</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="YourOrder_MainLoginEmail" type="submit" value="Login" />
        <span class="msg_error YourOrder_loginError_general">The user name or password provided is incorrect.</span>
    </p>
</form>
```

and this css:

```
.YourOrder_loginForm {
    position: relative;
}
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    display: none;
}
.msg_error {
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

use this script:

```
function ShoppingCartLogin(e) {

    var userid = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginEmail").val();
    var password = $(".YourOrder_MainLoginPassword").val();

    /* Hide all errors */
    $('.msg_error').hide();

    if (!userid) $('.YourOrder_loginError').show();
    if (!password) $('.YourOrder_loginError_password').show();
    if (!userid || !password) return false;

    /* No errors, proceed */
    $('.loading').show();
    var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"; /* Use your url here */
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        /* You should use POST here */
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            email: userid,
            website: password
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == "Valid")
            /* No need to hide anything, you reload the page */
            location.reload();
            if (result.error == "Invalid") $('.YourOrder_loginError_general').show();
            $('.loading').hide();
        },
        error: function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    });
    /* Prevent form submition */
    return false;
}

$('.YourOrder_loginForm').on('submit', ShoppingCartLogin);
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7gar6nwL/).